# C++ Read Contents of a file into a unsigned char array of bytes

Tags: c++

I've been experiementing with a function I found that allows running an Executable in memory in the same address space. 
Source : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Zer0Mem0ry/RunPE/master/RunPE.cpp

It's really interesting, I'd like to know how it works, Also, One other thing I'm trying to do, Is having my Bytes saved in a text file, And I'm trying to get the program to read those bytes and Execute it. 
Here's my code so far, But it does not work because I can't seem to figure out how can I convert the data read from the file to an unsigned char with those bytes.

```cpp
int main()
{
    //char buffer_bytes[90000] = { 0 };
    std::ifstream read;
    std::stringstream buf;

    std::cout << "Reading bytes from text file (bytes.txt)." << std::endl;
    read.open("bytes.txt", std::ios::binary);
    if (read.is_open())
    {
        buf << read.rdbuf();
        RunPortableExecutable(buf.str().c_str());
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "[ERROR] Failed reading " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    read.close();
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A text file would corrupt the binary data. Although with that said you are reading it as binary.

Comment: Then we write it in a binary file. I just want a way to be able to read those bytes in from a file and Execute them with ``RunPortableExecutable(void *Image);``.